# Change URL woocommerce "Return to shop"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

for some reason I get this when i hit return to shop:

This site can’t be reached

```
xn--%20%20%20-zyhgadab9cq9cg1a6brlgdd9aqmj4akrf8l9b8c’s server DNS address could not be found.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy, firewall, and DNS configuration
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I would like to change the URL to get back to the shop page: https://vemavm.com/test/shop/

Here is what i have on line:

```
<p class="return-to-shop">
    <a class="button wc-backward" href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink ('shop') ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Return to shop', 'xclean' ) ?></a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function your_theme_prefix_continue_shopping_redirect_url($url) {
$url = 'https://www.google.co.in/'; // Add your custom link here
return $url;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', 'your_theme_prefix_continue_shopping_redirect_url');
```

Change the URL value according to your need.

Comment: Where to insert the code? Under additional css? Because I tried there and it gives me errors.

Comment: You need to add this code to functions.php file of your theme.

Comment: At the end of the functions.php file? Asking too much because I am not into coding and scared might mess up something.

Comment: yes, you can just paste this code into functions.php file at the bottom. Please do take backup of the functions.php file before pasting this code.

Comment: Can you share your functions.php file

Comment: Do you have an email so i can send it to you? Stackoverflow doesnt let me paste the whole thing since its too long.

Comment: you can send here pappsbj[at]gmail. com

Comment: do you have a different email? It bounced back.

Comment: Send your email id I will text you

Comment: tony.zammit[at]mail.com

Answer (score 0):

There is not rocket science just add this function in the function.php

```
 // cart page return to shop link
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', 'tm_get_shop_link' );
  // continue shopping redirect
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', 'tm_get_shop_link' );
  function tm_get_shop_link() {
    return get_site_url();
  } // end function
```